# How to attached additional information with Property of class in .net

Tags: .net, class-design

I want to create a business entity. I want to store additional information with each property

e.g.

```
    Public Class BE
    {
        private string _fundCity;

        public string FUND_CITY 
        {
            get { return _fundCity; }
            set { _fundCity = value; }
        }
    }
```

For FUND_CITY  i want to store "StartOffSet" and "EndOffSet"  values in BE.
Can some one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have properties that are directly related to `FUND_CITY` then normally you would make it an object in its own right and add the properties to the new object, and you can still store it in your object `BE` as you are now.

If you want `FUND_CITY` to remain as a string, then you must add `StartOffset` and `EndOffset` as properties on the `BE` class, just as you have with FUND_CITY. I would give you an example but you haven't specified what types those two properties are.

## EDIT:

It sounds like what you need is a wrapper class with a shot of generics. If you want to track `StartOffset` and `EndOffset` for **every** property on `BE`, then first create a generic class that will be used for each property in BE:

```
public class MyProperty<T> 
{
    public MyProperty(T propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    public int StartOffset { get; set; }
    public int EndOffset { get; set; }

    public T PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

`PropertyValue` is used to hold (or *wrap*) the actual value of the property. Your class `BE` then changes to look like this:

```
public class BE
{
    public MyProperty<string> FUND_CITY { get; set; }

    public MyProperty<int> SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

you can then use it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var myBE = new BE();
        myBE.FUND_CITY = new MyProperty<string>("some random string value") { StartOffset = 0, EndOffset = 10 };
        myBE.SomeOtherProperty = new MyProperty<int>(999);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you want to go still further and keep a list of these, then you can use the inbuilt generic [List<T> type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), but then you have a small issue: the List<T> wants all its contents to be of the same type. You can get round this either by using a base class, or by just casting everything in the List<T> to type `object`. Here is an example of using the base class, it has a small change from the code above:

```
public class MyPropertyBase
{
    public int StartOffset { get; set; }
    public int EndOffset { get; set; }
}

public class MyProperty<T> : MyPropertyBase
{
    public MyProperty(T propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    public T PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

public class BE
{
    public MyProperty<string> FUND_CITY { get; set; }

    public MyProperty<int> SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public List<MyPropertyBase> MyDataPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Those two properties would be of type int. There would many others properties on my class of types string, int, double, decimal and Generic collection, apart from these property types, i want to keep two additional values "StartOffSet" and "EndOffSet" for each property.

Comment: I heartly thanks. Looks it will work. Little problem - when i assign value to the property it give - Can't implicitly convert myproperty<string> or mypropert<int>?

Comment: @user - that is correct, instances of `MyProperty` will either be `string`, `int`, etc., converting between these types is a whole other question. You cannot go `var dataPoint = new MyProperty<int>(); dataPoint.PropertyValue = "12345";` (you cannot assign a string to an int property, C# is a strongly typed language). If you use the `List<MyPropertyBase>` approach then you can store different types of DataPoints in the List. If you have further questions then it might be best to post a new question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate class (note that my syntax is using VS2010 auto-setter properties; if you are using an earlier version you will need to create the properties the old-fashioned way:

```
public class FundCity
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int StartOffSet {get; set;}
  public int EndOffSet{get; set;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

public class BE
{
private FundCity _fundCity;
 public FundCity FUND_CITY 
        {
            get
            {
              return _fundCity;
            }
             set 
            {
               _fundCity=value;
            }
        }
}
```

**Update with Generic solution**

```
public class DataPoint<T>
{
    public T value {get; set; }

    public int StartOffset {get; set; }
    public int EndOffset { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}

public class BE
{
    public DataPoint<String> FUND_CITY { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank for Reply. Like FUND_CITY, we will have many other properties  on BE and we will required StartOffSet and EndOffset for each property, then how i will get and set these additional values for each property. I want keep type of FUND_CITY as string.

Comment: Still i want Fund_City as string type.

Comment: Are the startoffset and endoffset going to be hard-coded or do they need to be updated?

Comment: I updated the answer to add the name, which I forgot in the original answer

Comment: In BE Class, we will have around 180 Data Points (Properties) like (FUND_CITY) of different data types, and each data point (property) will store StartOffSet and EndOFfset in addition to its own type. If opt to design a class as suggested, then we will need to create 180 additional classes for each DP?

Comment: Unless the values are hard-coded, then your only option is to have a class. However, you do NOT need one for each property. If all of the values are the same (i.e. strings), then you can use the class I provided for each property, just renamed. Otherwise, you can create 1 generic class that would accept the data type for the value.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a generic-based solution.

Comment: Yep, that is supported by the generic solution. Basically, just wrap each data type in DataPoint<>, for example DataPoint<double>  REDEMP_FEE_MONTH

Comment: Actually our BE would be  :                                                         public Class BE
{
  double REDEMP_FEE_MONTH { get; set; }
         double ADMINISTRATOR_FEE_BREAKPNT { get; set; }
         double BROKER_COMM_AMOUNT { get; set; }
}   We need to store informtion  like objBE.BROKER_COMM_AMT=1200 objBE.BROAKER_COMM_AMT.StartOffset= 15001 objBE.BROAKER_COMM_AMT.EndOffset=15005, ObjBE.REDEMP_FEE_MONTH=6 objBE.REDEMP_FEE_MONTH.StartOffset= 18561 objBE.REDEMP_FEE_MONTH.EndOffset=18562 ..... etc.

Comment: @competent_tech: while using generics is the way to go, your solution doesn't cover the requirements of *we will have around 180 Data Points [...snip...] of **different** data types*

Comment: @slugster: it actually does if you look at the refining comments above, the data types are primitives (double, string, etc) and the generic solution covers that (DataPoint<double> for example).